# Extract Variable Values Using For Loop in R

Tags: r

I have 102 different models in R that are titled "model1", "model2", "model3" ... "model102", that are encoded as lists. They each have the exact same structure where the 9th element retrieves the AIC value. I am looking to use a for-loop (or any method really) that can extract the AIC value for each of my models, order the AIC values from lowest to highest, and put the ordered values in to a new data frame.

I have experience using Python and thus my original thought was to use Regex to concatenate a string and number sequentially within a for-loop. Unfortunately I have little R experience and I am unsure of how to extract the AIC value from each variable.

Any thoughts? Thanks!

```
number <- seq(1,6,1)
modelList <- paste(name,number,sep = "")

for (i in 1:length(number)) {
  print (modelList[i]$AIC)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `base R` option would be to get the values of the objects into a list (assuming that the model identifiers are named 'model1', 'model2', ..., 'model102'), loop through the `list` with `sapply`, extract the 'AIC' values, `sort` it and create a 'data.frame' with one column

```
lst1 <- mget(paste0("model", 1:102))
aicV <- sapply(lst1, function(x) x$AIC)
d1 <- data.frame(aic = sort(aicV))
```

Comment: This works perfectly! Thanks for the help, it is much appreciated!